# match a list of functions against a list of parameters

Tags: haskell

If we have a list of functions `[f1,...fn]` and a list of parameters `[a1,...,an]`, is there a simple way (in Haskell) to produce something like `[fn a1, ..., fn an]`? I have been looking and only found a function called `sequenceA`, but it returns all posible matchings, and in the case I'm considering each f is only necessarily defined for the corresponding parameter. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is [`zipWith`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:ZipList):

```hs
zipWith ($) fs xs -- fs is the list of functions, xs is the list of values
```

Simple simon. Hope that helps.

Comment: So simple! Thank you!